# How to implement this statistical error for Monte Carlo sampling 2D Ising model?

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics, physics, montecarlo

I'm having a problem with the Python implementation of this statistical error equation that I found in "Monte Carlo simulations in statistical physics" by Binder(page 94, 2014). First of all, the main body of code of concern for my algorithm looks like:

```py
SCALE_11 = DISCARDED_SAMPS/(MC_STEPS*L*L)
SCALE_22 = DISCARDED_SAMPS*DISCARDED_SAMPS*SCALE_1/MC_STEPS
for k in range(NT):
    E1 = E2 = M1 = M2 = np.float_(0.0)
    inv_T = 1.0 / T[k]  # beta = 1/k_B*Temperature, set k_B = 1
    prob = np.exp(-4*inv_T*np.array([0,1,2], dtype=np.uint8))
    p_i = []
    lattice = 2*np.random.randint(2, size=(L, L), dtype=np.int16)-1

    for i in range(EQ_STEPS):   # equilibrate
        sweep(lattice, prob)# 1 sweep = L**2 Monte Carlo moves per EQ_STEP
        for i in range(MC_STEPS):
            sweep(lattice, prob)

   for i in range(MC_STEPS)
        sweep(lattice, prob)                
        if i % DISCARDED_SAMPS == 0:       # the remainder
            energy = hamiltonian(lattice)      # calculate the energy
            mag = abs(np.sum(lattice))     # calculate the magnetisation

            E1 += energy         # the estimator
            M1 += mag            # the estimator
            E2 += energy*energy  # the estimator
            M2 += mag*mag        # the estimator
   E[k] = SCALE_11*E1
   M[k] = SCALE_11*M1 
   C[k] = (SCALE_11*E2 - SCALE_22*E1*E1)*inv_T*inv_T
   X[k] = (SCALE_11*M2 - SCALE_22*M1*M1)*inv_T
```

Basically in my algorithm I'm iterating over a range of different temperature and do the Monte Carlo simulation. At each temperature my first loop equilibrates the system and my second loop further sweeps it and make an observation at every `DISCARDED_SAMPS`(`DS`) steps because the samples are correlated.

The `E, M, C, X` are the energy, magnetisation, specific heat and susceptibility(all per spin) respectively. The specific heat and susceptibility equations have the form
[image]

Now in my algorithm the `<E^2>` and `<E>` is done on the code, essentially I'm just performing
[image]

which was quite straight forward. But now I'm looking to implement a statistical error equation from the aforementioned textbook where it's given as:
[image]

Where `A` is an observable which can be `E, M` etc. I'm having problem implementing this equation if we take `n` as number of times `i % DISCARDED_SAMPS == 0` happened and `A^2`, `A` are now averages over `MC_STEPS` and `A_0` is the observable before the first `i % DISCARDED_SAMPS == 0` happened. How could one possibly implement this on Python?